# Hide <p:messages> by clicking on embedded Submit button

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to close my messages dialog without using the built in close button. An embedded "CLOSE" button within the message needs to fire of a method in the backing bean, and when finished, the message box should close.

My code calls the actionListener, but I am unable to clear the message box on submission. In my last attempt, I tried to do it from the Backing Bean, but the box refuses to go away.

Below is sample test code.

```
    <h:form id="form1">
        <h:panelGroup id="myPanel" layout="block" class="scap-block"
            rendered="#{not chartView.acknowledged}">
            <p:messages id="banner" showSummary="true" showDetail="false"
                autoUpdate="true" closable="true" escape="false">
            </p:messages>
            <p:commandButton widgetVar="acceptContinue"
                style-class="align right" value="Close" type="ajax"
                actionListener="#{chartView.close}" render="myPanel" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{chartView.init}" />
    </h:body>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "chartView")
@ViewScoped
public class ChartView implements Serializable {

private boolean acknowledged = false;

public void init() {

    log.debug("preRender init() method");

    String detail = "PrimeFaces Rocks."
            +"<button aria-disabled='false'  id='form1:j_idt5' name='form1:j_idt5' "
            + "class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only' "
            + "onclick='PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;form1:j_idt5&quot;});return false;' type='ajax'>"
            + "<span class='ui-button-text ui-c'>Close</span></button>";

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("banner",
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, detail, "Some details"));
}


public void close() {
    System.err.println("Acknowledged");
    log.debug("###Close called###");
    setAcknowledged(true);
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update(":form1:myParent");
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of page]

Comment: You talk about `p:message` in your title but you have a `p:messages` in your code. You talk about 'messages' in your text. And putting html in there which would normally be generated by JSF is 'dangerous'. Try to add a plain button (PF styled if you like) and on the 'onclick' click the real button via javascript (which you e.g. hide via css)

Comment: I've changed as suggested.  I had to put the html into the primefaces message to get it to render the required button inside the messages box, is there a JSF-specific way of doing this?

Comment: I realised that the p:messages wasn't necessary for me, so I've just reverted to making an output panel with a submit button, and added the JQuery code from a p:message panel to close it.

Comment: Solutions belong in answers, not as edits to the question.